# How to check how much GPU memory is used by object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, memory-management

I wonder if there is any way to determine how much memory object or group of objects is going to use while rendering.

I was trying to follow some of recent Blender Guru's tutorials but it seems like I have complex object (trees) which even if set alone on separate layer, take too much RAM.

Is there any alternative?

1. Trying to simplify object?
2. Is it possible to render part of scene on GPU and part on CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Objects like trees or toothbrushes take up much memory.
For trees, even games use [object instancing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication). While copying the tree, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This will keep you from editing the trees individually but will keep the memory requirement low, you can also have a few trees and create an illusion by rotating them, (fake it!)

Too many leafs will unevitably result in high memory need. I strongly recommend you to take a look to [this cycles instancing test](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?249664-.bend-bench-19-Billions-of-Polygons-not-a-ridiculous-number-anymore).

If you don't want to lower the details, you can try caching the required files on your computer(cycles only). To do this, you need to use the (Cache BVH) checkbox under the "performance" section of render tab.
User preferences also let you to adjuct the available RAM to use.

Comment: Thanks! I used linked copy (ALT+D) for trees. The issue I have is that even 1 tree is too much for my GPU. I was wondering if there is a way to check how much RAM will be required by simple object or group. I'll check out Cache BVH and instancing test.